# Array of queues not compiling - cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a radix sort going with an array of queues to avoid long rambling switch statements but I'm having some trouble getting the array properly initialized. The constructor and an example of an implementation are given below.

I'm just getting a cannot find symbol error when I try to compile though.

```
 public static radixj(){
    IntQueue[] buckets = new IntQueue[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    buckets[i] = new IntQueue();
   }

 public static void place(int temp, int marker)
 {
  int pos = temp % marker; 
  buckets[pos].put(temp);
 }
```

I'm pretty sure it is a really simple mistake that I'm making but I can't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What symbol? What's an `IntQueue`? Is it in a package? Did you import it if the code shown is in a different package?

Comment: The method `public static radixj()` also lacks a return type. Unless it is supposed to be a constructor. In that case it should not be `static` (and the class name should be capitalized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
IntQueue[] buckets = new IntQueue[10];
```

is a local variable to the function

```
public static radixj()
```

which must have a return type

```
public static void radixj()
```

So then you can't use it in another function

```
buckets[pos].put(temp);
```

You should declare a static class variable

```
class Foo {
    static IntQueue[] buckets = new IntQueue[10];
    ...
```

and access it using: `Foo.buckets`

```
class Foo {
    public static IntQueue[] buckets = new IntQueue[10];
    public static void radixj() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Foo.buckets[i] = new IntQueue();
        }
    }

    public static void place(int temp, int marker) {
        int pos = temp % marker;
        Foo.buckets[pos].put(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the return type in `radixj()` is missing and `buckets` cannot be resolved to a variable